# Errors in my haml file in a ruby on rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, haml, html2haml

I'm following a tutorial to make a forum! when I wrote this code in the index.html.haml

```
- @posts.each do |post|
  %h2= post.title
%p 
Published at
= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at)
= link_to "New Post", new_post_path
```

I got this errors :

> app/views/posts/index.html.haml:7: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end
>   app/views/posts/index.html.haml:10: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

I really need your help!

Comment: You know HAML is indentation-based, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it may be an indentation problem. Try this:

```
- @posts.each do |post|
  %h2= post.title
  %p 
    Published at
    = time_ago_in_words(post.created_at)
= link_to "New Post", new_post_path
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have typed "end" at the end of your method and have another "end" that as the last line of code in your model.

Without seeing your code, it looks like your missing the "end" syntax somewhere.

Comment: HAML does not need the "end" keyword. It handles scope by indentation.

Comment: no my code hasn't any error well I found the solution. thank you :)